# Convert a string to Linq.Expressions or use a string as Selector?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

Well I have a string now that has the expression value to be evaluated..it has say value `expr => expr.FieldName` ... so I want to use this string as Linq. Expression or any other way to query...like `Select(str)`. 
Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't personally used it, the Dynamic Linq Library might be useful for you. Check out ScottGu's post: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: I have tried Scott Gu's Dynamic Library before and didnt work for me some issue with my side...I need to fix..So I was looking for something else. But thanks for your reply...