# how to turn a string into a linq expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, generics

Similar: [Convert a string to Linq.Expressions or use a string as Selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783432/1026459)

A similar one of that one: [Passing a Linq expression as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3280422/1026459)

Another question with the same answer: [How to create dynamic lambda based Linq expression from a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10114841/1026459)

Reason for asking something which has so many similar questions:

The accepted answer in those similar questions is unacceptable in that they all reference a library from 4 years ago (granted that it was written by code master Scott Gu) written for an old framework (.net 3.5) , and does not provide anything but a link as an answer.

There is a way to do this in code without including a whole library.

Here is some sample code for this situation:

```
    public static void getDynamic<T>(int startingId) where T : class
    {
        string classType = typeof(T).ToString();
        string classTypeId = classType + "Id";
        using (var repo = new Repository<T>())
        {
            Build<T>(
             repo.getList(),
             b => b.classTypeId //doesn't compile, this is the heart of the issue
               //How can a string be used in this fashion to access a property in b?
            )
        }
    }

    public void Build<T>(
        List<T> items, 
        Func<T, int> value) where T : class
    {
        var Values = new List<Item>();
        Values = items.Select(f => new Item()
        {
            Id = value(f)
        }).ToList();
    }

    public class Item
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that this is not looking to turn an entire string into an expression such as

```
query = "x => x.id == somevalue";
```

But instead is trying to only use the string as the access

```
query = x => x.STRING;
```

Comment: Have you ruled out doing simple reflection to make your `Func`?

Comment: @PaulPhillips - Reflection will yield the property type or name of the property in class T which is passed in. Class T is passed in only as a reference for type when connection to an Entity Framework Repository. A list of all Class T is returned from the repository (`repo.getList()`). How would reflection help in including properties from Class T in the linq expression?

Comment: Your example made it look like you're doing linq-to-objects, in which case you could grab the value of the property reflectively. But since you're working in another context, I'm not sure it would work. I posted my attempt so you could check

Comment: Thought about it more, it won't work. The expression tree will just see the text of the function, not get the value.

Comment: @PaulPhillips - Thanks for the suggestion, I am definitely looking at all avenues.

Comment: If you want to put a bounty on this question you should do so, saying such-and-such answer will be bountied is silly.

Comment: @Hogan - Sorry, I cannot post a bounty for another 2 days. If I could I would. Perhaps that is an issue you can raise on meta.

Comment: @Travis - Well I guess it didn't matter because I solved your problem anyway :D  enjoy.

Comment: Nobody has suggested opening LinqPad and seeing what they do?

I distinctly remember this being included as an example with the Roslyn CTP, and they had an example of how to do it the "old" way (without Roslyn).  

I think they compiled c# into a memorystream and then executed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's an expression tree attempt. I still don't know if this would work with Entity framework, but I figure it is worth a try.

```
Func<T, int> MakeGetter<T>(string propertyName)
{
    ParameterExpression input = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));

    var expr = Expression.Property(input, typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(expr, input).Compile();  
}
```

Call it like this:

```
Build<T>(repo.getList(), MakeGetter<T>(classTypeId))
```

If you can use an `Expression<Func<T,int>>` in place of a just a `Func`, then just remove the call to `Compile` (and change the signature of `MakeGetter`).

---

**Edit**: 
In the comments, TravisJ asked how he could use it like this: `w => "text" + w.classTypeId`

There's several ways to do this, but for readability I would recommend introducing a local variable first, like this:

```
var getId = MakeGetter<T>(classTypeId);

return w => "text" + getId(w);
```

The main point is that the getter is just a function, and you can use it exactly like you normally would. Read `Func<T,int>` like this: `int DoSomething(T instance)`

Comment: I was able to get this to work in linqPad -- here is the code https://gist.github.com/3108507

Comment: @Paul - Thank you for some working code and example. I was also able to get this to work. I did not change the signature because it would have interfered with more linq down the line. I did have one question, what would I have to do to use `MakeGetter` in this way: `w => "text" + MakeGetter<T>(classTypeId)`? Similar to `w => "text" + w.classTypeId`.

Comment: @PaulPhillips - Thank you for the edit, and clarification. Although I have read a lot of documentation at MSDN and around the web I am still getting used to delegates, Funcs, and Expression trees. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an extension method for you with my testing code (linqPad):

```
class test
{
   public string sam { get; set; }
   public string notsam {get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
   var z = new test { sam = "sam", notsam = "alex" };

   z.Dump();

   z.GetPropertyByString("notsam").Dump();

   z.SetPropertyByString("sam","john");

   z.Dump();
}

static class Nice
{
  public static void  SetPropertyByString(this object x, string p,object value) 
  {
     x.GetType().GetProperty(p).SetValue(x,value,null);
  }

  public static object GetPropertyByString(this object x,string p)
  {
     return x.GetType().GetProperty(p).GetValue(x,null);
  }
}
```

results:

[image: results]

Comment: This works in your example, however, I see no integration with linq here. See Paul's answer for a linq integration.

Comment: I guess, his works on a type mine works on an object... 6 of one.  I think mine would be more performent since there is no templating needed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, and not sure if it would work, but could you use something like:

`b => b.GetType().GetProperty(classTypeId).GetValue(b, null);`

Comment: This looks interesting and at least compiles. Still have more testing to do.